# Is a non-negative random variable with zero mean almost surely zero?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

We have proven the following in class:

> If $X$ is a *finite* random variable with $X\geq 0$ then $$E(X)=0  \iff  P(X=0)=1$$ (By *finite* I meant that the range has finitely many elements).

Does it hold for any non-negative random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R_{\geq0}$?

(I've tried proving it with the indicator function yet it didn't help.)

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that X can now take any real value, rather than restricting X to $\ge 0$ ? Or do you mean substituting some arbitrary value in for E(X), $E(X)=A:A\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

In either case, the answer is no.

Comment: @Justaskin_: I mean not restricting $X\geq 0$ to be finite.

Comment: You mean that $X$ can take the value $+\infty$?  Assuming that, then your supposition is correct.  Suppose that $P[X=0]=1$.  Then the expected value is $\int x\,\textrm{d}P$, which is bounded above by $0\cdot 1+\infty\cdot 0=0$.  Conversely, suppose that $P[X=0]<1.$  Then there is some $\epsilon>0$ and $\mu>0$ such that $P[X\geq \epsilon]>\mu$.  It follows that $E[X]\geq\mu\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @Unwisdom: doesn't your integral imply that we have a density function? And by _finite_ I meant that the range has finitely many elements, as opposed to (un)countable, etc.

Comment: I don't think that I am assuming the existence of a density.  After all, I am integrating with respect to $P$. Anyway, now that I know what you mean by "infinite", I'll work through the details more carefully in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that, for every $x\gt0$,
$$
X\geqslant x\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant x}.
$$
(This is the step where one uses that $X\geqslant0$ almost surely.) It follows that
$$
E(X)\geqslant xP(X\geqslant x).
$$
If $E(X)=0$ this inequality implies that $P(X\geqslant x)=0$. Finally,
$$
[X\gt0]=\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}[X\geqslant1/n],
$$
hence, if every event in the RHS has probability zero the event on the LHS has probability zero.

Comment: Is there a nice proof for the other direction? (And many thanks for this neat proof.)

Comment: You mean, P(X=0)=1 implies E(X)=0? Well, yes...

Comment: One question about the step where you use that $X⩾0$ almost surely. If we see $aP(X⩾a)\leqslant E(X)$ as the integrated version of $a\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant a}\leqslant X$ then the issue with almost surely is clear (since the integral won't notice us leaving out the zero measure set). But we didn't have the $\int_\Omega X \ \text{d}\mathbb P$ definition in the course. Is there a way to understand the step without the integral?

Comment: How did you define E(X) then?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle \Omega,\mathcal{F},P\rangle$ denote our probability space.  The expected value of $X$ is $$E[X]=\int_{\Omega}X\, \textrm{d}P.$$

If we let $U\in\mathcal{F}$ be $X^{-1}\{0\}$, then we can decompose the exectation:
$$E[X]=\int_{U}X\, \textrm{d}P+\int_{\Omega\setminus U}X\, \textrm{d}P=\int_{\Omega\setminus U}X\, \textrm{d}P.$$

(The second equality follows from the fact that $X(\omega)=0$ for $\omega\in U$.)

Now, suppose that $P[\Omega\setminus U]>0$. Since $$\forall \omega\in (\Omega\setminus U)\, \big(X(\omega)>0\big)$$ 
there must be some $\epsilon>0$ and some $V\subseteq(\Omega\setminus U)$ such that $P[V]>0$ and $$\forall \omega\in V \, \big(X(\omega)>\epsilon\big).$$
Thus:
$$E[X]=\int_{\Omega\setminus U}X\, \textrm{d}P \geq \int_{V} X\, \textrm{d}P \geq \int_{V}\epsilon\,\textrm{d}P = \epsilon P[V]>0.$$

For the converse direction, suppose that $P[U]=1$.  Then $P[\Omega\setminus U]=0$ and so we get:
$$E[X]=\int_{\Omega\setminus U}X\, \textrm{d}P = 0.$$