# Polynomial Markov Inequalities Tight?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, moment-generating-functions

Recall the Polynomial Markov Inequality:

> Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $X$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[|X|^k] < \infty$. Then, for all $t > 0$, we have that (denoting $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu$)
> \begin{equation*}
> P(|X-\mu|\geq t] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X-\mu|^k]}{t^k}.
> \end{equation*}

Now, it can be shown that the inequality is tight for when $k = 1$ and 2, consider the following random variables:

- $X$ such that $P(X = t) = \lambda$ and $P(X = 0) = 1- \lambda$ for the given $t$;
- $X$ such that $P(X = -t) = P(X = t) = \frac{1}{2}$ for the given $t$.

See [Markov's inequality tight in general?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347085/markovs-inequality-tight-in-general) for the arguments for why these work (or merely compute).

However, I might be missing the pattern in the construction, but how does one construct a random variable such that the Polynomial Markov is tight for any given $k$?