# Explanation of the proof about correlation

Tags: statistics, correlation

Here's the statement: Correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y)$ is equal to 1 (-1) $\iff$ there exist numbers $a\ne0$ and $b$ such that $P(Y=aX+b)$

The proof goes like this:
Let $f(t)=E[((X-E(X))t+(Y-E(Y)))^2]=\dots =t^2var(X)+2tcov(X,Y)+var(Y)$. So $|\rho(X,Y)|=1 \iff$ the discriminant is equal to 0 ($f$ has a single root). Since $((X-E(X))t+(Y-E(Y)))^2\geq0$, $f(t)$=0 $\iff$ $P((X-E(X))t+(Y-E(Y))=0)=1$. Now we do some algebra stuff to arrange it in the desired form.

I can't understand the last iff statement: $f(t)$=0 $\iff$ $P((X-E(X))t+(Y-E(Y))=0)=1$. Why does this hold?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708779/is-a-non-negative-random-variable-with-zero-mean-almost-surely-zero

Comment: Of course, I'm stupid. Thanks a lot.